# Flash AS3 advance to next frame with hitTestObject

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, hittest, cs3

Hi guys needing some help here. Basically i want to advance to frame 4 after (guy1) hits the hitTestObject (home1_mc).

**This is the error i get:**

```
ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
    at DNAGames2_fla::MainTimeline/exitFrameHandler()
ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
    at DNAGames2_fla::MainTimeline/exitFrameHandler()
```

**And this is my code:**

```
function exitFrameHandler(event:Event):void{
if(guy1.hitTestObject(home1_mc)) {
        removeChild(guy1);
        removeChild(guy2);
        removeChild(guy3);
        removeChild(o1);
        removeChild(cherry1);

        gotoAndStop(4);         
    }       
}
```

the reason i have tried removing the child is due to them still being on screen after i switch menus for my game. any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should also add in the handler:

```
removeEvetListener(EVENT_TYPE, exitFrameHandler);
```

If the listener is called twice you'll get that exact error - because the first time it removes the children and the second time you try to remove display objects which are no longer  children of the container.

Comment: Thanks , all give it ago and see if it works . It was for my assement a few days ago but doesnt hurt to know more ;l)